# sudo stopped working

Tags: sudo, opensuse

In the middle of working on something in openSUSE 12 sudo suddenly stopped working with the following error:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: unable to load /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so: (null)
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

What can cause this and how can I fix it? I can still ssh as root into the machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use the root account:

```
$ su root     #enter password
$ chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
$ chown -R root /usr/lib/sudo
```

Else you'll have to startup in recovery mode, get write permission on your disk, and change the mode of that file.

```
$ mount -o remount,rw /
$ chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
```

Comment: Looks like the remount worked, simply doing chmod on sudoers didn't have any effect, but after the remount the error stopped. Do you know what might have caused it? I was simply doing a "sudo cp somefile", nothing special, really

Comment: Well maybe an update did hit the lib and permissions got wrong. A simple cp should not do that. Take a look on apt get logs